# Cookie in PHP is not ready

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I have an web application in **CakePHP** but my question is about **PHP**.

I have an application (EX: APP1) that I want to use it with other application (EX: APP2).

When I run APP2 I need the **cookie/PHPSESSID** for stay connected with APP1 so I should send PHPSESSID from APP1 to APP2.

When I use **$_COOKIE** for it the first time it's an array empty like **array()**.

I write this code for test in **APP1**:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

it shows an empty array but in debug mode of Google chrome, it existes.

When I press F5 the output is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

When **APP2** send a request tp **APP1** after login the **APP1** will send a message to **APP2** that login is successful and also in cookie file it sends the **PHPSESSID**